# ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '[us-cdbr-azure-sat-02.cloudapp.net]' (0)

Tags: mysql, azure

I am new to php, mysql, azure and web programming in general, so excuse me for my poor knowledge.

when I try to connect to the remote mysql database on azure using the following command:

```
mysql -h[us-cdbr-azure-sat-02.cloudapp.net] -u[myAzureUSer] -p[myPassword] -D[myDB]
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '[us-cdbr-azure-sat-02.cloudapp.net]' (0)
```

any idea why I would be getting that?! I have wamp installed on my windows 7 local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using square brackets (`[` `]`) where they don't belong. Get rid of them.